# How to move arrow up or down in contenteditable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `html` table in which I can write anything and tabs work. But I am trying to make up and down arrow work as well. I tried few scripts online but not able to make any of those work as those are for particular scenarios. like:

```js
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    switch(e.which){
        case 37: // left arrow            
            $(e.target).closest('td').nextAll('td.editable:first').find('div');
            break;
        case 39: // right arrow
            $(e.target).closest('td').nextAll('td.editable:first').find('div');
            break;
        default: // exit for other keys
            return;
    }
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent default action
});
```

```css
table{
    border: 1px solid black;
    table-layout: fixed;    
}
tr {
    height: 28px; 
    width: 30px;
}
td{
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table style="width: 600px;border: 1px solid black;">
<tbody>
<tr style="height: 16px;">
<td colspan="6" style="text-align: center; height: 16px; border: 1px solid black;">
<p><strong>Groups</strong></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="border: 1px; border-color: red;">
<td><p style="text-align: left;"><em><strong>Areas</strong></em></p></td>
<td style="border-color: red;border: 1px solid red;"><div  class="editable"></div></td>
<td style="border-color: red;border: 1px solid red;"><div  class="editable"></div></td>
<td style="border-color: red;border: 1px solid red;"><div  class="editable"></div></td>
<td style="border-color: red;border: 1px solid red;"><div  class="editable"></div></td>
<td style="border-color: red;border: 1px solid red;"><div  class="editable"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="border-color: red;border: 1px solid red;"><div class="editable"></div></td>
<td><div class="editable"></div></td>
<td><div class="editable"></div></td>
<td><div class="editable"></div></td>
<td><div class="editable"></div></td>
<td><div class="editable"></div></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Is there a simple script that will make arrows usable in this table?

Comment: Pls check you example code and provide a working one. It's not clear what you're asking for. Which arrows are you talking about?

Answer (score 2):

This would be considerably easier with class names for the `<td>` or `<div>` elements, but in their absence, here is a solution. See https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/ for more info.

Also, use `.focus()` to focus the field:

```js
$(document).keydown(function(e) {

  switch (e.which) {
    case 37: // left arrow       
      $(e.target).parent().prev().find('div').focus()
      break;
    case 39: // right arrow
      $(e.target).parent().next().find('div').focus()
      break;
    case 40: // down
      $(e.target).parent().parent().next().children().eq($(e.target).parent().index()).find('div').focus()
      break;
    case 38: // up
      $(e.target).parent().parent().prev().children().eq($(e.target).parent().index()).find('div').focus()
      break;
    default: // exit for other keys
      return;
  }

});
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<table style="width: 1400px;border: 1px solid black;">
  <tbody>
    <tr style="height: 16px;">
      <td colspan="6" style="text-align: center; width: 979px; height: 16px; border: 1px solid black;">
        <p><strong>Groups</strong></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr border: 1px; border-color: red; ">
<td><p style="text-align: left; "><em><strong>Areas</strong></em></p></td>
<td style="border-color: red;border: 1px solid red; "><div contenteditable>fgjhdfjdg</div></td>
<td style="border-color: red;border: 1px solid red; "><div contenteditable><sadffsf</div></td>
<td style="border-color: red;border: 1px solid red; "><div contenteditable>zxcvxzcv</div></td>
<td style="border-color: red;border: 1px solid red; "><div contenteditable>cvbnvbn</div></td>
<td style="border-color: red;border: 1px solid red; "><div contenteditable>REQZX</div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="border-color: red;border: 1px solid red; "><div contenteditable>CVBXCB</td>
<td><div contenteditable>HJM,HJ</td>
<td><div contenteditable>ASDFAS</td>
<td><div contenteditable>NBCN</td>
<td><div contenteditable>RTWETB</td>
<td><div contenteditable>XCVBXCB</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<style>
table{
    border: 1px solid black;
    table-layout: fixed;    
}
tr {
    height: 28px; 
    width: 100px;
}
td{
    border:1px solid #000;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it better to use all 4 arrow keys?

1. Use **[`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/)** for down <kbd>↓</kbd> and right <kbd>→</kbd> arrow keys.
2. Use **[`.prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)** for up <kbd>↑</kbd> and left <kbd>←</kbd> arrow keys.
3. Keep track of your position with **[`.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/)**
4. Use **[`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)** to find the `<td>` and `<tr>` (or [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) if from **[`e.target`](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/)** to `<tr>`).
5. Use **[`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)** and the return index number of `.index()` to find the same positioned `<td>` in a neighboring `<tr>`.

Confused? ...me too just take a look at the Demo.

### Demo

**Details commented in comments**

```js
/* Don't know if you already made the divs contenteditable but
|| if you haven't yet, here's a simple way of doing it.
*/
$('.editable').attr('contenteditable', true);

// Delegate the keydown event to Document Object
$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
  // Prevent default action
  e.preventDefault();
  /* Establish references to all elements that could possibly be
  || involved. 
  */
  // Reference the <div> being typed into
  var start = $(e.target);
  // Reference the <td> that the <div> is the child of
  var cell = start.parent('td');
  // Reference the <tr> that the <td> is child of 
  var row = cell.parent('tr');
  // Determine the index position of the <td>
  var idx = row.find('td').index(cell);
  //console.log(idx);

  switch (e.which) {
    // Up 
    case 38:
      /* Find the <tr> that's above the current <tr>
      || Find the <td> in the same position as current <td>
      || Find the <div> in that <td> 
      */
      row.prev('tr').find('td').eq(idx).find('.editable').focus();
      break;
      // Left
    case 37:
      /* Find the <td> that's to the left of current <td>
      || Find the <div> within that <td>
      */
      cell.prev('td').find('.editable').focus();
      break;
      // Right
    case 39:
      /* Find the <td> that's to the right of current <td>
      || Find the <div> within that <td>
      */
      cell.next('td').find('.editable').focus();
      break;
      // Down
    case 40:
      /* Find the <tr> that's below the current <tr>
      || Find the <td> in the same position as current <td>
      || Find the <div> in that <td> 
      */
      row.next('tr').find('td').eq(idx).find('.editable').focus();
      break;
      // Ignore other keys
    default:
      return;
  }
  // Stop event bubbling
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

tr {
  height: 28px;
  width: 30px;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table style="width: 600px;border: 1px solid black;">
  <tbody>
    <tr style="height: 16px;">
      <td colspan="6" style="text-align: center; height: 16px; border: 1px solid black;">
        <p><strong>Groups</strong></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="border: 1px; border-color: red;">
      <td>
        <p style="text-align: left;"><em><strong>Areas</strong></em></p>
      </td>
      <td style="border-color: red;border: 1px solid red;">
        <div class="editable"></div>
      </td>
      <td style="border-color: red;border: 1px solid red;">
        <div class="editable"></div>
      </td>
      <td style="border-color: red;border: 1px solid red;">
        <div class="editable"></div>
      </td>
      <td style="border-color: red;border: 1px solid red;">
        <div class="editable"></div>
      </td>
      <td style="border-color: red;border: 1px solid red;">
        <div class="editable"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="border-color: red;border: 1px solid red;">
        <div class="editable"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="editable"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="editable"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="editable"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="editable"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="editable"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```